# How to use Money filter in active admin?

Tags: activeadmin

I am using money-rails gem for monetary values. I wanna have filter on this field. The values stored in DB are saved in cents, but filter is to  be applied on actual values only.

Comment: Can you post a example for how the data is stored in the DB

Comment: Data stored in db is in cents(multiplied by 100). So if actual price amount is 289, data stored in db will be 289 *100 = 28900.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom runsacker for that.

```
# in your model
ransacker :price_money, formatter: proc { |v| v.to_i * 100 } do |parent|
  parent.table[:name]
end

# in your admin file
filter :price_money
```

Comment: Tried same

ransacker :price_money, formatter: proc{|v| v * 100} do |parent|
    parent.table[:price_cents]
 end



But getting error on search. If i use 5 as filter input, Error is
'5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4'

Comment: The problem was with typecasting. In proc, it was getting string, which needed to be converted to integer.
proc { |v| v.to_i*100 }

Answer (score 2):

Use `_r` instead of `_i` to preserve your cents, otherwise it will round it out. So same answer as Timo Schilling's post but with that small adjustment.

```
# in your model
ransacker :price_money, formatter: proc { |v| v.to_r * 100 } do |parent|
  parent.table[:name]
end


# in your admin file
filter :price_money
```